# Merging txt files as columns into csv with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

Sorry if this question has already been asked, but I can't for the life of me find a valid answer.

I have a bunch of .txt files each containing a column of content. I would like to merge them in one .csv where the columns will be next to each other.

So if the first input in1.txt is:

```
banana
pear
apple
orange
```

and the second one, in2.txt is

```
airplane
truck
car
bus
```

I would like the resulting csv, say out.csv, to be:

```
banana,airplane
pear,truck
apple,car
orange,bus
```

Is there a way to do that with Powershell?

Comment: Yes there is a way to do that. I would suggest looking at the `Get-Content`, `New-Object`, and `Export-CSV` commands and writing some code. When you have specific code issues you can post back here and we will help you.

Comment: Also be aware that the text files need to have exactly the same number of entries in each file or else you will need to write your code to handle situations where they do not.

Comment: @EBGreen thanks for your input. I was actually completely stuck trying to concatenate objects instead of making a loop, so much so that I didn't have anything that remotely worked. This is why I didn't publish any code, because it didn't need debugging but completely rethinking. Sorry if I came across as not wanting to give it a try, and thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. In the future though posting what you have tried even if it is not close at all is a good idea. If nothing else it gives us some indication of where your knowledge level is so we can craft an answer that is more appropriate for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i'm agree with EBGreen both comments, but to guide you with some direction...

In case your both files are in the same length, you can use simple for loop, if 
not, you should work a bit harder, but you can start with this as an idea...

```
$txt1 = Get-Content C:\txt1.txt
$txt2 = Get-Content C:\txt2.txt

$csv = @()
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Txt1.Count; $i++){
$row = "" | Select txt1,txt2
$row.txt1 = $txt1[$i]
$row.txt2 = $txt2[$i]
$csv += $row
}

$csv | Export-Csv c:\txt.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved it. I was completely stuck with attempts at concatenating the different objects, so much so that I didn't think about making a loop, which in retrospect seems obvious. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just as an FYI, if the files are very large at all using an ArrayList rather than an Array is much faster.

Comment: sure, but just to keep it simple